# How to get gradient effect on background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get the gradient effect in unity game on bacground. There is any c# solution for that or I need to use preset pack?

I want something like on the picture

https://imgur.com/9e7475fb-ea04-475a-8fb3-dcad40694c41

Comment: image doesn't exist

Comment: btw, you can use [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/914545/view.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the window tab in unity 
 click on rendering
 Click on lightning
you can change bg from here by giving your meterial

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradient API to create gradient effect in unity.

for example :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour

{
    Gradient gradient;
    GradientColorKey[] colorKey;
    GradientAlphaKey[] alphaKey;

    void Start()
    {
        gradient = new Gradient();

        // Populate the color keys at the relative time 0 and 1 (0 and 100%)
        colorKey = new GradientColorKey[2];
        colorKey[0].color = Color.red;
        colorKey[0].time = 0.0f;
        colorKey[1].color = Color.blue;
        colorKey[1].time = 1.0f;

        // Populate the alpha  keys at relative time 0 and 1  (0 and 100%)
        alphaKey = new GradientAlphaKey[2];
        alphaKey[0].alpha = 1.0f;
        alphaKey[0].time = 0.0f;
        alphaKey[1].alpha = 0.0f;
        alphaKey[1].time = 1.0f;

        gradient.SetKeys(colorKey, alphaKey);

        // What's the color at the relative time 0.25 (25 %) ?
        Debug.Log(gradient.Evaluate(0.25f));
    }
}
```